# did Shader Graph's interface change? nothing looks right

Tags: unity3d

first of all, I created the shader from 'create/shader/universal Render Pipeline/sprite lit shader graph' instead of 'create/shader/2d renderer/sprite list shader graph'

creating the shader graph:

[image]

next, I am greeted with "Vertex" and "Fragment" instead of "Sprite Lit Master" as in [Brackey's 2d shader tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5dzGj9k8Qy8&t=291s) and THEN properties are just obsolete! look, I have this Texture2D property and it's just blank

the graph:

[image]

---

what do I do? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score -1):

yes, the interface did change. to access the settings of a parameter (or any node for that matter) go to the "Node Settings" tab under the *Graph Inspector*. The *Vertex* and *Fragment* nodes **are** now the master node. they were separated to match shader programming conventions.

[Refer to this video for more details](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-QcwEYOHt2I)

Comment: Please do not refer to videos for answers. All information should be in the answer. If the link disappears the answer will be useless for future readers.

Comment: I mean, I *did* answer the question. I only neglected the other details. It should be fine now tho.